# BitMap Checkpoint-Workaround Please

Tags: qtp

I need to compare layout of 2 files(pdf). So i used Bit Map checkpoint. When i run using the normal run mode i am getting error message as **Expected and actual bitmaps are of different sizes.** Then I tried to run via as Update mode and it was working good. Then again i tried to execute via normal run i am again getting same error message.

What is the workaround for this, since I also tried with checkpoint run settings too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already try to set up the tolerance? You can go to Advanced Settings and set a RGB and pixel tolerance. Also, you need to make sure that you are using always the same monitor size, for example, if you recorded a bitmap in a 24'' monitor, the image will have X pixels of width and Y of height, if you run your test in a monitor of 15'' for example, the script will try to compare the actual image (that is smaller) with the one that is larger. So, all of this things affects the bitmap checkpoint.